# Git on Windows: How do I ignore a folder that has dots in its name

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

I have a directory like that :'dir1/dir2/blah.blah.blah.blah/'
'blah.blah.blah.blah' is folder how do I add it to .gitignore?

I tried:
dir1/dir2/blah.blah.blah.blah/*

Comment: This should "just work" as is, but as [toydarian noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133183/git-on-windows-how-do-i-ignore-a-folder-that-has-dots-in-its-name#comment111640812_63133387), make sure the file is not *tracked* (i.e., is not in Git's index right now: use `git ls-files` to see every file in Git's index, or `git ls-files dir1/dir2/` to see every file that's in `dir1/dir2/`).

Comment: You are right the problem was unrelated to the dots but rather the way .gitignore was set. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Rather than deleting it, see if you can find a question and/or answer about how to set up the `.gitignore` file for Windows that matches what the actual issue was, and mark this as a duplicate. If you can't find such a question, post your own answer. That way the next time someone on Windows has the same problem, they can find this question and the answer.

Comment: Apart from what @torek said, this is still a valid question on how to escape dots in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @toydarian: dots aren't special in `.gitignore` lines, as these are glob patterns, not regular expressions. (It *is* worth wondering whether `*` matches files whose name *starts with* `.`, since sh/bash normally doesn't. The answer in Git is "yes, they match": this is the way bash handles `*` matching if the `dotglob` option is set.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `.` in your `.gitignore` file like this:
`blah\.blah\.blah\.blah`

If this does not work, you probably added the directory to git earlier. In this case, you need to remove it from git (`git rm <directory>` and then `git commit`) but this will also remove it from the working directory, so backup the files if you still need them!
Use `git ls-files dir1/dir2/` as suggested by torek in the question's comments to check if the directory has been added to git.

To remove a file or directory from repository, you can use this:

```
git rm -r --cached <file/directory>
git commit -m "removes <file/directory>"
```

This will not remove anything from the history though. The files can still be accessed when checking out an older commit.
It will also not remove the actual files in the directory, it will just make git not longer track them.

Comment: or you can always, assuming one of the blahs' unique, *blah*/

Comment: Tried it twice not working, I am doing it over Windows if it make any difference.
the final line was: ' dir1/dir2/blah\.blah\.blah\.blah/

Comment: It works correctly on linux. You might want to tag the question `windows`. Btw. if the directory was already added to git, the entry in `.gitignore` is ignored. In this case you need to remove it with `git rm` (but this will also remove it from the working directory!).